# Open a file dialog from JavaScript not working here

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [In JavaScript is it possible to launch a file browser dialog programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209509/in-javascript-is-it-possible-to-launch-a-file-browser-dialog-programatically)

I have tried the below code to open the file-dialog. But the trigger click is not firing. Please help me on this

```
$('body').append('<input type="file" id="a">');
$('#a').click();
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dn3W/) is the fiddle I have tried

Comment: @sergei tulentsev Current browsers are too modern than the browsers when that question was answered. :-)

Comment: Do you want this?
http://jsfiddle.net/TACsw/

Comment: @mgechev No, Please have a look at the fiddle I have provided as an update.

Comment: @Sol oops, didn't notice the date :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't fire the `click` event in all browsers for Security reasons. What you can do instead, is [use a CSS technique](http://www.burhankhan.com/css_tricks/styling-file-upload-input-box-in-css/) of [making the file upload invisible](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) (with an opacity filter), and then showing something else.

When the user clicks on your 'something else' they are actually clicking on the file upload input.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you meant that http://jsfiddle.net/4dn3W/1/

```
$('body').append('<input type="file" id="a">');
$('#a').click(function (event) {
    var dialog = $('<div id="dialog" title="File dialog">My dialog</div>');
    $(event.target).css('display', 'none');
    $(document.body).append(dialog);
    dialog.dialog({ width: 450 });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you add the code into the answer?