# How can I hide the "TextBox" of the FileUpload control?

Tags: asp.net, button, file-upload, textbox, hide

In my ASP.NET page I am using the "FileUpload" control.
The whole thing is implemented and is working as expected but...
I don't want the TextBox control which is a part of "FileUpload". (FileUpload = TextBox + Button)

Is it possible that I can remove/hide only the TextBox and let the Button look like a LinkButton?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using control adapters? Here is a simple sample code that will do the job for you, without the CSS cleverness :) [http://blog.mathiaskunto.com/2012/01/28/keeping-your-hair-from-turning-gray-or-how-to-style-the-aspfileupload-control-using-control-adapters/](http://blog.mathiaskunto.com/2012/01/28/keeping-your-hair-from-turning-gray-or-how-to-style-the-aspfileupload-control-using-control-adapters/)

Answer (score 10):

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" style="display: none;" />
<input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
```

This will surely work. i have tried it in my project.It dosent require javascript or CSS.

Comment: there is no asp.NET here... nice beside of that

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can use this trick:

```
FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
fileUpload.Width = Unit.Pixel(83);
```

The button is 83 pixels and the textbox is the rest. If you force the control to a width of 83 pixels then the button is shown and the textbox is not.

Comment: While this does work, it is somewhat hacky and is prone to css and\or cross-browser issues.

Answer (score 3):

For Asp.Net with HTML5 you can use document.getElementById('<%=ServerControlID.ClientID%>') to solve this issue.

My working code

**HTML5**

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />
 <input type="button" value="Browse" onclick="showBrowseDialog()"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showBrowseDialog() {
    var fileuploadctrl = document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>');
    fileuploadctrl.click();
}
```

Works in Firefox, IE & Chrome.

Comment: Please forgive my JS ignorance.  I copied and pasted those lines in to my code and replaced my FileUpload control.  But when I get to my codebehind and FileUpload1 has no PostedFile.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The fileUpload control is not style-able since it is sandboxed from the page for security. With HTML5 you can do your own file uploading or you can alternatively use flash, but otherwise you're stuck with what the browser gives you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it's nasty. It involves some javascript and CSS cleverness to basically make the control invisible, placing an image in the background behind it.

[See this answer from a couple years back.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209509/in-javascript-is-it-possible-to-launch-a-file-browser-dialog-programatically)